# How Do I Count Unique Rows In Sql Vb.Net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a sql datbase with the following:

Product: Amount:

- PCB1 2
- PCB1 6
- PCB2 54
- PCB2 23

im interested in counting the amount of the same product and displaying it in a datagrid view.

just after the sql command and following code to populate the datagridview.

So i would see in the datagridview:

Product: Amount:

- PCB1 8
- PCB2 77

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Many Thanks,
Pete :)

Comment: Pretty basic SQL syntax Search for GROUP BY and SUM.

Comment: 5 cents - 4 ways. 1 - let db engine to summarize for you. Get all records over to client and 2 -you can use Linq or 3 - Ado.Net `dataTable` capability. Or even worse, 4 - you can iterate records "manually" and write your own logic. Choose your poison.

Comment: @T.S., I've always found LINQ as a stand-alone reference term to be pretty ambigious in this context. The DataContext, or DbContext, in LINQ To SQL feels like a better way to scope and relate it to people who are so early in their development. `Or even wrose, 4 -` this is something people will do regardless to what manner they use to make the connection, then stream, buffer, serialize.... this sort of goes with `1 - let db engine...` as well; this would be a post connection and stream aspect, right? providing data 'to be' serialized by the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pseudo code that load the datagridview with the required query

```
Using con = new MySqlConnection(....)
Using cmd = new MySqlCommand("select product, Sum(amount) from tableName GROUP BY product", con)
   con.Open()
   Dim dt = new DataTable()
   Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      dt.Load(dr)
      dataGridView.DataSource = dt
   End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Note that you need to use the correct tableName for your data and add the information about the connectionstring to be used when you create the connection

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the answer :) quick question, is it hard to alter that code to count how many times the same product is in the db? e.g. if the product didnt have an amount and purely relied on counting the names, and give the same effect in a datagridview? Many Thanks

Comment: Just add another column in the query that is the result of _count(product)_ i.e. _select product, count(product) as productcounter, sum(amount) as totalproduct from tablename group by product_

Answer (score 1):

You will need to supply the connection string and the correct table name. The following code also assumes a DataGridView named DataGridView1.

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
sqlconn.ConnectionString = "SQL CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE"
Dim strSQL As String = "select product, SUM(amount) from tableName group by product"
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
Dim mySqlCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlconn)
Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
sqlconn.Open()
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: how would i populate a datagridview with this code ?

Comment: @PeterJames, a bindable control's datasource member can be any class with public/accessible properties. You can modify design aspects using System.Attributes, and implement interfaces that the bindable controls use for underline mechanisms, like the actually 'binding' mechanism, which takes you implementing IPropertyNotify on your class.

Comment: @PeterJames, the DataGridView actually expects the object assigned to the DataSource Member to implement IEnumerable(of Object), which means you can just dim and assign a List(of Object) to the datasource, and the DataGridView would use the IEnumerable<T> interface of the List<T> to enumerate through the items of the list, and it would generate number of columns and the controls in the columns by reflecting on the properties of T, where T is Object.. It can, of course, be anything that inherits from Object.. which is EVERYTHING.. so that's some underline mechanism to consider and elate.

Comment: @PeterJames, with the 'you can DO' being said, the `DataSet` being populated by the SqlDataAdapter and assigned to the DataSource of the DataGridView (control) already has those interfaces and mechanism support in place.. Considering that your data is coming from a database - which will return a tubular record set (no collection/list/array in a column/field) - you will probably not even have cause to consider assigning your own class and such....